# array in php class "Undefined variable"

Tags: php, arrays, class

I started to learn PHP. I have written a class and I defined an array in that.

```php
<?php

/**
 *
 */
class page {

    public $content= "Coming soon";
    public $title="Saeb Mollayi";
    public $style ="<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"./style/style.css\">";
    public $b = array(
        "خانه"       => 'homepage.php',
        "ارتباط"     => 'contact.php',
        "خدمات"      => 'services.php',
        "نقشه سایت"  =>'sitemap.php',
    );


    function displaymenu()
    {
        echo "<table>"."\r\n";
        echo  " <tr>";
        $width=(100/count($b));

        while (list($name,$url)= each ($b))
        {
            $this -> displaybuttons ($width,$name,$url, $this -> urlbool($url));
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
    }

    function ncontent($newcontent)
    {
        $this-> content = $newcontent ;
    }

    function ntitle($newtitle)
    {
        $this -> title = $newtitle ;
    }

    function nbuttons($newbuttons)
    {
        $this -> b = $newbuttons ;
    }

    function display()
    {
        echo "<head>";
        echo "\r\n";

        $this -> displaytitle();
        $this -> style ;

        echo "</head>"."\r\n"."<body>"."\r\n";

        $this -> displayheader();
        $this -> displaymenu($this -> b);

        echo $this -> content ;

        $this -> displayfooter() ;
        echo "</body>"."\r\n";
    }

    function displaytitle()
    {
        echo "<title>";
        echo $this -> title ;
        echo "</title>";
    }

    function displayheader()
    {
        echo '
        <table  id="header">
            <tr id="header">
                <td id="lheader"><img src="./img/logo1.png"></td>
                <td id="cheader"> Welocme. Welcome! </td>
                <rd id="rheader"><img src="./img/logo1.png"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        ';
    }

    function urlbool($url)
    {
        if (strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],$url)==false)
            return false;
        else return true;
    }

    function displaybuttons($width,$name,$url,$active=false)
    {
        if (!active) {
            echo "<td \" style =\"width=$width% ;\">
                <a href ='$url'>
                <img src=\".\img\top.png \" alt='$name' border='0'></a>
                <a href='$url' ><span class='menu'>$name</span></a>
                </td>";
        } else {
            echo "
                <td style='width=$width%'>
                    <img src='./img/right.png'>
                    <span class='menu'>$name</span>
                </td>";
        }
    }

    function displayfooter()
    {
        echo "&copy footer";
    }
}
?>
```

This is my index.php file:

```
<html>
<?php
    require "./class/page0.inc";
    $cc = array(
        'خانه'      => 'homepage.php',
        'ارتباط'    => 'contact.php',
        'خدمات'     => 'services.php',
        'نقشه سایت' =>'sitemap.php',
    );

    $ppage = new page();
    $ppage-> nbuttons(array(
        'خانه' => 'homepage.php',
        'ارتباط'=> 'contact.php',
        'خدمات' => 'services.php',
        'نقشه سایت' =>'sitemap.php',
    ));
    $ppage -> ncontent('this is content'."<br>");
    $ppage -> display();
?>
</html>
```

But when I run it I see these errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: b in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/all/test3/class/page0.inc on line 14
>
> Warning: Division by zero in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/all/test3/class/page0.inc on line 14
>
> Warning: Variable passed to each() is not an array or object in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/all/test3/class/page0.inc on line 15

Where i did do something wrong? What is my fault?

Comment: possible to clean up and indent some for readabilities sake?

Comment: You are invoking `$this -> displaymenu($this -> b);` with a parameter - `$this -> b`, but your function declaration does not have a param -> `function displaymenu(){...}`. You need to change it to `function displaymenu( $b ){...}`

Comment: "What is my fault?" - If this happens the first time... not knowing the rules (for accessing member variables) - failing to read the documentation or a book. If this happens again: lazyness.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath made my day.

Comment: :D im working in my english and php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's because in the copy/paste something went wrong, but editing your post I found out that there are a lot of syntax errors.

First of all those spaces in the objects function calls, where you have unnecessary spaces.

The *arrow* should not have any space like `$this -> displaymenu($this -> b);`, it has to be `$this->displaymenu($this->b);`.

In addition `$b` must be referenced using `$this->b`, that's why you get that error about dividing by zero.

Comment: tnx . i must use $this->b every where i have $b in function. tnx

Comment: You're welcome! If this was your solution it would be kind if you select it as your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Text in errors in readable by humans, they means:

1. Variable $b does not exist in your function on line 14 in page.inc file.
2. Because $b does not exists, PHP function "count" will return 0 and you have division by zero.
3. You are passing variable $b to a function "each", $b does not exists and it is not an array or object.

If you have a variable $b inside class, use $this->b instead to access to it.